# Rails find_by_sql does not return requested columns from associated tables/models

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Question: Why is p.name not returned?

```
sql = "
SELECT reports.id, reports.address, p.name 
FROM reports
JOIN places_reports pr ON reports.id = pr.report_id
JOIN places p ON pr.place_id = p.id
WHERE reports.id = 14
"

Report.find_by_sql(sql)
```

Returns:

```
#<Report id: 14, address: "New Gisborne, vic, Australia">, #<Report id: 14, address: "New Gisborne, vic, Australia">]
```

Documentation is a little vague, but seems to allude that it should be returned as an attribute of Report.

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class

Comment: This is because you’re running find_by_sql on the Report model. It will only return attributes of the report table. Instead, you could try ‘ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql)’ which returns an array of hashes.

Comment: cheers mate! Makes sense.

Comment: @AJFaraday The values are there and can be accessed in the usual way even if the `#inspect` output doesn't include them.

Comment: @muistooshort how can they be accessed? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote an answer a couple hours ago but forgot to post it. Must be getting old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value you're seeing:

```
#<Report id: 14, address: "New Gisborne, vic, Australia">, #<Report id: 14, address: "New Gisborne, vic, Australia">]
```

is `#inspect` output and that only includes columns that `Report` knows about. The extra values from the SQL are still there and have accessor methods so you can say things like this:

```
sql = %q(
  SELECT reports.id, reports.address, p.name 
  FROM reports
  JOIN places_reports pr ON reports.id = pr.report_id
  JOIN places p ON pr.place_id = p.id
  WHERE reports.id = 14
)
Report.find_by_sql(sql).each { |r| puts r.name }
```

and it will work. You could also add aliases to the SQL to get "better" method names:

```
sql = %q(
  SELECT reports.id, reports.address, p.name as place_name
  FROM reports
  JOIN places_reports pr ON reports.id = pr.report_id
  JOIN places p ON pr.place_id = p.id
  WHERE reports.id = 14
)
Report.find_by_sql(sql).each { |r| puts r.place_name }
```

Comment: Heya! Thank you so much, between these two answers I have a path forward.  Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

I commented in haste, while I wasn't near a computer, and missed that you can access the attributes which don't belong to a record by the records selected by find by sql.

Here are other options:

If you don't want functionality defined in your model, you can get the raw data by dropping back to the database connnection and calling `select_all`, which returns an array of hashes.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql)
# [{'id': 1, 'address': '123 fake street', 'name': 'harry'}]
```

You can also name these attributes however you like in the SQL itself:

```
sql = <<-SQL
  SELECT reports.id report_id, reports.address, p.name place_name
  FROM reports
  JOIN places_reports pr ON reports.id = pr.report_id
  JOIN places p ON pr.place_id = p.id
  WHERE reports.id = 14
SQL
```

---

Alternatively, if you want funcitonality from the model (or both models) you can include these in your select. e.g.

```
report = Report
  .includes(report_places: :places)
  .where(report_id: 14)
  .first
# Runs 3 SQL statements up-front (no matter how many records are found)
report.places
# No SQL staements run, array of Place model instances returned
```

---

As @mu-is-too-short points out, you can just grab the attributes against the Report instances, but there are a few reasons I wouldn't choose to do this.

- There would be multiple instances of Report returned with the same ID but a different name.
- It gives a false impression that name is an attribute of Report. This could be confusing when you come back to the code.

Comment: Thanks @AJFaraday.  I agree with your alternative solution. That's ultimately what I was looking for, but unsure how to construct it.  Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [AJFaraday](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3088748/ajfaraday)

```
sql = "
SELECT reports.id, reports.address, p.name 
FROM reports
JOIN places_reports pr ON reports.id = pr.report_id
JOIN places p ON pr.place_id = p.id
WHERE reports.id = 14
"

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql)
```

Comment: While this gets it done, see @AJFaraday 's answer for a better way to do it.